# Check if type implements IDictionary<T, V> with specific type of T

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dictionary

I wonder if, in .NET, it's possible to check if a given `Type` implements `IDictionary<T, V>` with T (the key type) being a specific type.

I have a method:

```
public bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {}
```

I want to return true for types like this:

```
Dictionary<Amount, double>
Dictionary<Amount, string>
Dictionary<Amount, whatever>
IDictionary<Amount, double>
IDictionary<Amount, whatever>
```

So I don't care what the type of the value is, as long as the key type is `Amount` (a class of mine).

Other dictionaries (for example `IDictionary<string, string>`) should return false.

In case you're wondering: this is for a custom JSON.NET converter.

Is it possible? I know I can check if it's a Dictionary or IDictionary:

```
var implementsDictionary 
    = objectType
          .GetInterfaces()
          .Any(x => x.IsGenericType 
                    && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (IDictionary<,>));

var isDictionary 
    = objectType
          .IsGenericType 
          && objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>);
```

But how can I check the Key type?

Comment: Mm yes, possibly. But how do I 'cast' my Type object to a Dictionary<?,?> and to what do I cast? Or can I cast to the open generic type Dictionary<,>, and if so, how?

Comment: Try this: `return objectType.IsGenericType && dictType.GetGenericArguments()[0] == keyType;` where `keyType` would be `typeof(Amount)`